# QUnit tests rely on page "onload" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, qunit

I have a form that contains a lot of select elements, all of which are populated from a database on page load using AJAX.

**Code from test_form.js.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing: 'form.js'</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/qunit-1.12.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/qunit-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialLoad();">
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="caseEntryForm">

        ...form stuff...

        <label for="CourtOfOrigin">Court of Origin</label>
            <select name="CourtOfOrigin" id="CourtOfOrigin">
                <option value="">--error--</option>
            </select>

        ...form stuff...

        </form>
    <div>
    <script>
        // QUnit auto start has been set to false so onload can finish first, so start the test engine
        QUnit.start();

        // Testing CrossAppeal onchange listening function
        test( "CrossAppeal onchange listening function Test", function() {
            ...assertions that all pass if this is the first test to run...
        });

        // Testing Outcome onchange listening function
        test( "Outcome onchange listening function Test", function() {
            ...assertions that all pass if this is the first test to run...
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code from form.js:**

```
function initialLoad(){
    $.post('processAjax.php', { field: 'Courts' }, function (data) {
        var target = $("#Outcome");
        target.empty();
        target.append('<option value="">--select--</option>');
        for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            target.append('<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Option + '</option>');
        }
    }

    ...about ten more ajax calls populating select elements from different tables...

}
```

**Code from processAjax.php:**

```
require('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
    if ($_POST['field'] == 'Courts') {
        // Process Ajax requests to load the CourtOfOrigin and SCOrigin <select>s
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT CourtName FROM ref_courts");
        $returnArray = array();
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $returnArray[] = array('Value' => $row['CourtName'], 'Option' => $row['CourtName']);
        }
        echo json_encode($returnArray);
    } else if ( ... ) {
        ...further ifs that handle other select elements and tables...
    }
    ...
}
```

So all of this works fine as far as the form goes. The calls always work and populate the select objects properly.

Now I'm trying to use QUnit to test all of the other functions in form.js that manipulate objects in the form based on user input. (ie. Show/hide elements based on what option has been selected in a select element.) If I only run one test, this works fine and all my tests pass. However, as soon as I add a second test, the tests start alternating between passing and failing.

I have researched this thoroughly and I know exactly why this is, however I cannot for the life of me find a solution.

The reason is, as soon as the first test is finished, QUnit resets the "qunit-fixture" div, as you would want. But it resets it right back to the initial code that in there, BEFORE the onload JavaScript function was called, which means that my select elements are now empty again, thus causing the next test to fail. Then the reason a refresh causes them to switch around which one passes and fails is because QUnit runs the failed tests first. I understand all this and it makes sense.

What I need to be able to do is somehow run the initialLoad() function between every test, as this is the real initial state of the form. I could obviously work around this issue if I hardcoded the select options into the form for the tests, but I would rather not do this as I feel this would not be truly testing the JavaScript, plus some of the selects have a lot of options.

I have spent a number of hours trying to find a solution, but so far haven't found anything that works. I have tried simply calling initialLoad() at the beginning of each test, but this won't work because the test will finish way before the AJAX calls have actually returned. I have also tried using stop() and start() but have had no success. (This could just be an implementation issue, though?)

This is how I was trying to do the stop():

```
// Testing Outcome onchange listening function
test( "Outcome onchange listening function Test", function() {
    stop();
    initialLoad();
    setTimeout(function() {
        ok(true);
        start();
    }, 500 );

    ...assertions that all pass if this is the first test to run...
}
```

However, they still failed on ever alternating refresh.

So I tried doing it like this:

```
// Testing Outcome onchange listening function
test( "Outcome onchange listening function Test", function() {
    stop();
    initialLoad();
    setTimeout(function() {

        ...assertions that all pass if this is the first test to run...

        start();
    }, 500 );
}
```

And I get mixed results. Previously, all assertions failed. But now, all the assertions that deal with changing the selected value PASS every time, so the select objects have obviously been populated now. However, when these options have been changed, it should trigger a function that shows/hides elements. These assertions FAIL every alternating time. (I get the same situation whether I have start() at the beginning or end of the function.) I've tried bumping the timeout to as high as 10,000 but it makes no difference.

So I kind of feel like I'm on track, but I'm not sure why the onchange functions aren't executing on alternating refreshes... There doesn't seem to be any reason why this should happen, when the conditions seem to be met EVERY time...

**UPDATE:** While trying to help someone else out with a problem, I came across [QUnit.testStart()](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testStart/) and [QUnit.testDone()](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testDone/), which sound like they could be used for a solution. I would think that calling "initialLoad();" in testStart() before each test would ensure that the fixture is in the correct condition before each test is run, however I still get the same alternating results. Is this because initialLoad() wouldn't have finished running yet? I can't understand why none of these above methods are working for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qunit test alternates between pass and fail on page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800739/qunit-test-alternates-between-pass-and-fail-on-page-refresh)

Comment: I don't see how that is a duplicate...

Comment: `the tests start alternating between passing and failing`...

Comment: Yes, but if you read my whole post, I know WHY it's alternating.
What this (my) question is about, is trying to find a way to populate the fixture div in between individual tests.

Comment: I don't see any references to `"qunit-fixture"` in the JavaScript. The [QUnit self-tests](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/test/test.js#L597) have examples which may help.